# Returning sum on value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my DataFrame:

```
email            title       id
---------------------------------
balh@blah.com    Title a    123
blah@gmail.com   Title b    824
new@blah.com     Title a    179
```

I'm calling;

```
counts = merged_df['title'].value_counts()
```

which returns:

```
Title a  2
Title b  1
```

What I want to be able to do is return a sum of all the counts for all titles. So, in this case, I want to return the value 3.

Comment: Why not just `merged_df['title'].count()`?

Comment: @JohnGalt : Totally obvious! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Just call .sum method on returned pandas Series:

```
total = merged_df['title'].value_counts().sum()
```

which will return

```
In : total
Out: 3
```